# CSS does not work on controls added dynamically to row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp-classic

I have a table where in I dynamically add rows with controls using javascript.

My problem is these controls are linked to CSS linked class.

```
<div id="DataTable">
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addNewRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteSelectRow('dataTable')" />

    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD>Name</TD>
            <TD>Country</TD>
            <TD>Security</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt"/></TD>
            <TD>
                <SELECT name="country">
                    <OPTION value="in">Greece</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="fr">India</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="ch">France</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
            </TD>
            <td>
                <Select name="secName2" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Security(s)">
                    <option value="000"></option>
                    <%sQuery = "Select sID,SecurityName from SecurityMast where Active = 1 order by SecurityName"
                    Set oRS = oConn.Execute (sQuery)
                    if Not (oRS.EOF and oRS.BOF) then%>
                    <%Do While Not oRS.EOF%>
                    <option value="<%Response.Write(oRS(0))%>"  
                            <%if sID=oRS(0) then Response.write "Selected"%>> <%Response.Write(oRS(1))%></option>
                    <%oRS.MoveNext
                    Loop%>
                    <%end if
                    oRS.Close%>
                </select>
            </td>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</div>
```

and my javascript looks liks this

```
function addNewRow(tID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tID);

        var roCount = table.rows.length;
        var ro = table.insertRow(roCount);

        var coCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<coCount; i++) {

            var newcell = ro.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
```

ok so now my problem is ...

when the user clicks add row we have a new row, but the drop down "SecName2" does not have the effects of class="chosen-select".

Is there anything that can be done about it.

What's special about class MySelect.  Well besides the cosmetic matter there is a search box that helps to search for anything anywhere in the select list.  Not just the starting characters which is default.

Appreciate your time and help

Vin

Edit:

I used the open source from http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/  for the select.

there is a script section at the end ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(".chosen-select").chosen(); $(".chosen-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true}); </script>
```

Comment: My guess is that you have some code that is binding to the Myselect objects.  It binds to the ones that are there when the table starts, but doesn't bind to the ones that you add dynamically because it has already been run so it doesn't know about them.  You'd either have to bind it to the new elements manually or switch the code to use delegated event handling so it works with dynamically created elements automatically.  Since you don't show us that code, there's not much we can do to make further suggestions about that code.

Comment: how do i bind to the new elements manually?

Comment: You'd have to show us what the code was that was hooking up to them when the page was loaded.

Comment: I used the open source from http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: have edited the main question.  pls check.